# Testing NHibernate with SQLite "No Such Table" - schema is generated

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, sqlite

I'm trying to use an in-memory SQLite database to test my data layer which is provided by NHibernate.

I've read a load of blogs and articles about getting this setup but I'm now very confused as to why it isn't working.

The problem - when I run a unit test I get the error 'no such table: Student'.  The articles I've read suggest this is because the schema isn't getting generated, or, the connection is being closed between my SchemaExport and query.  I've checked everywhere I can think of and can't see how either of these scenarios are occuring.

My test output log looks like this:

```
OPEN CONNECTION

drop table if exists "Student"

drop table if exists "Tutor"

create table "Student" (
    ID  integer,
   Name TEXT,
   DoB DATETIME,
   TutorId INTEGER,
   primary key (ID)
)

create table "Tutor" (
    ID  integer,
   Name TEXT,
   primary key (ID)
)
NHibernate: INSERT INTO "Student" (Name, DoB, TutorId) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2); select last_insert_rowid();@p0 = 'Text1', @p1 = 01/12/2010 14:55:05, @p2 = NULL
14:55:05,750 ERROR [TestRunnerThread] AbstractBatcher [(null)]- Could not execute query: INSERT INTO "Student" (Name, DoB, TutorId) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2); select last_insert_rowid()
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): SQLite error

no such table: Student

at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, String& strRemain)

at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()

at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)

at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()

at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)

at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)

at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)

at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()

at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)

14:55:05,781 ERROR [TestRunnerThread] ADOExceptionReporter [(null)]- SQLite error
no such table: Student
DISPOSE
CLOSING CONNECTION
```

Originally I was using my own code for the connection/session management but have moved to the code in [this blog post](http://jasondentler.com/blog/2009/08/nhibernate-unit-testing-with-sqlite-in-memory-db/) translated to C# and with a couple changes to the DBConfig method and some debug statements to show the state of the connection.

```
private FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.IPersistenceConfigurer GetDBConfig()
{
    return SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
                               .ConnectionString((ConnectionStringBuilder cs) => cs.Is(CONNECTION_STRING))
                               .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu")
                               .Raw("connection.release_mode", "on_close");
}
```

I added the on_close after reading [this](http://www.codethinked.com/nhibernate-20-sqlite-and-in-memory-databases)

My test code looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void CanGetStudentById()
{
    using (var scope = new SQLiteDatabaseScope<StudentMapping>())
    {
        using (ISession sess = scope.OpenSession())
        {
            // Arrange
            var repo = new StudentRepository();
            repo.Save(new Student() { Name = "Text1", DoB = DateTime.Now });

            // Act
            var student = repo.GetById(1);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(student);
            Assert.AreEqual("Text1", student.Name);
        }
   }
}
```

What have I overlooked here?

**Update:** I created a copy of the class that connects to an SQLite file DB and it worked fine.  So it has to be something to do with the connection being closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your test method to the following, does it work?

```
[Test]
public void CanGetStudentById()
{
    using (var scope = new SQLiteDatabaseScope<StudentMapping>())
    {
        using (ISession sess = scope.OpenSession())
        {
            // Arrange
            sess.Save(new Student() { Name = "Text1", DoB = DateTime.Now });

            // Act
            var student = sess.Get<Student>(1);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(student);
            Assert.AreEqual("Text1", student.Name);
        }
   }
}
```

I would hazard to guess that your StudentRepository is opening its own session and hence doesn't see the table.

Comment: Of course!  Thank you so much!  That's exactly what the problem is.  Not sure how I'm going to work around it, but at least I know what I'm doing now :)  It also answers why my tests were conflicting with one another as well!

Comment: Take a look at Contextual Sessions (http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session) and specifically CurrentSessionContext and ISessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().